# Invalid Firebase path:Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDi2U.jpg)I have created signup page in kodular. I have stored the data in firebase. when i am storing the email.. there was an run time error."Invalid firebase path. Firebase paths must not contain '.','#','$','[' and ']'.I am the begginer for kodular. Please help me to solve the issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYKST.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS2QR.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried so far rather than a screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added code .help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that was a earning app & happing for device utilities Please change device utilities id to device utilities device id.